# Javascript change string to type function?

Tags: javascript

I have a list of functions stored as strings such as this one:

```
var act= "function () { alert() }";
```

I need to change the type of act from 'string' to 'function' so I can .call() it. I should end up with this:

```
act = function () { alert() };
```

How can this be done?

Comment: You could `eval()` it, but how come you've got such a string? Mostly this is not the best solution to your actual problem.

Comment: If you have the ability to change whatever architecture resulted in these being stored as strings, I recommend doing so. JavaScript functions can be passed around as references easily, and it would be simple to define all of them inside an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the few cases where using eval is not only valid but correct:

```
var act = eval(function_string);
```

However, I should note that having a bunch of functions in strings is a sign of bad design. Still, if you must then eval is the way to do it.

Comment: thanks, the problem is that I need to parse the functions to modify individual parts of them. (Change the condition, add a second line to the code block. And I haven't found a way to do it without turning them to strings first.

Comment: @Liso22: That's an even worse code smell than just needing eval. Hope you're not using it in production code (I honestly can't think of any reason why it would be needed for production since you can just serve the edited file instead). This does sound like something that might be necessary for browser plugins or bookmarklets

Comment: I need to generate complex functions dynamically to create/modify the behavior of the AI on a evolutionary game. I know if it's not ideal but I'm not aware of any other way to do it good or bad. I might post a question if you think there is. But from previous answers I doubt so

Comment: @Liso22: There are better ways to do that. Javascript is capable of higher order programming and you can apply all the algorithms that the Lisp guys invented for this with javascript. You can implement it as a rule engine for example. Or create a symbolic manipulation system that stores operations as pointers to functions in arrays.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var act = 'alert(5);';

act = new Function( act );
```

Comment: +1 for using a "safer" alternative to `eval`. Of course this sort of thing shouldn't be done anyway, but this is better ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`, although it is considered to be particularly unsafe if the string source is unknown. You can't really assign what you have there to any variable. `eval` argument has to be an **expression** or a **statement**. You can do something like this.

```
eval("var act = function () { alert('hey') }");    
act();​
```

Comment: It's only unsafe if you can't trust its source.

Comment: Executing arbitrary strings as code is unsafe. Eval is just one way to do it. Appending a script tag to your page is also unsafe for the same reason. And yet, a lot of people blindly trust external servers and pull libraries directly without realizing that what they're doing is just as unsafe as eval.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have to do it with eval. But many people consider it as evil (Be sure that you get the string from a safe source.)

```
var act= "function () { alert() }";
eval ('act = '+ act)
```